# proverb for friends in happy moments

Tags: phrases, expressions, american-english, british-english, proverbs

Is there any *proverb* in **English** for ***people that are friends with us in good moments of life but leave us alone in difficult times*** ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A ***fair-weather friend***

- someone whose friendship cannot be relied on in times of difficulty (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fair-weather_friend).
- a friend during pleasant or prosperous times; esp. one who is friendly or dependable only when it is easy or convenient to be so; an unreliable friend; also in extended use (OED).

1896   Spectator 15 Aug. 217/2   She belongs to the sad company of ‘reduced gentlefolk,’ and finds how short are the memories of ***fair weather friends***.

1922   C. J. Melrose Money & Credit ix. 187   A mixed currency..never was—it never could be—anything but a mere palliative—a ‘***fair weather friend***’.

1992   N.Y. Times Bk. Rev. 26 Apr. 27/3   Nick..takes revenge on ***fair-weather friends*** and becomes a genuine nice guy.

Comment: Yes, I think 'fair-weather friend' is spot on as an answer to the OP. However, may we have further and better details to enlighten us further.

Comment: Great expression but a bit fragmentary for what the OP requested.

Answer (score 2):

> A friend in need is a friend indeed.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/a_friend_in_need_is_a_friend_indeed

Comment: This (as usually phrased, as here) is a bit ambiguous. "A friend *when you are* in need is a friend indeed," is clearer, but not as euphonious nor as pithy.

Comment: @Pete - Unfortunately, I don't think we get to rewrite traditional proverbs.  I mean, you can make your own version, but you'd have to have quite a bit of influence over popular culture to make your revision stick.  (Also, I don't personally think your revision is necessary in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

"Sunshine soldier" is also used to denote someone who is there when the going is easy, but leaves when things become unpleasant.

Neither suggestion (so far) carries the connotation of "happy or good moments" however, merely easy *vs.* difficult.

Comment: I don't find many references to 'sunshine soldier' online. Do you think it might be a conflation of Thomas Paine's 'The summer soldier and the sunshine patriot'? http://www.ushistory.org/paine/crisis/c-01.htm

Comment: That is possible, but I find (using the Google ngram server) that "sunshine soldier" enjoyed a vogue in the late 1800s and then has showed up fairly regularly (but with less frequency) ever since. http://bit.ly/2dg7zAi